# How to keep the original image after cropping in PIL for easy adjustment later?

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, crop, aspect-ratio

I am trying to group crop a folder full of images using PIL, basically resizing them from PC wallpapers to iPhone wallpapers. Sometimes, it crops in a way which works. But other times, a slight adjustment is needed to where the crop ended up. Is there any way to keep the rest of the image after PIL crops it, for easy adjustment later?

I've tried the standard resize and crop from PIL but no dice so far.

This is the code I have:

```
for image in gis.results():
    image.url  # image direct url
    image.referrer_url  # image referrer url (source) 
    image.download(r'C:\)  # download image
    image.path  # downloaded local file path
def main():
    outPath = r"C:\"
    path = r"C:"

    # iterate through the names of contents of the folder
    for image_path in os.listdir(path):

        # create the full input path and read the file
        input_path = os.path.join(path, image_path)
        im = Image.open(input_path)
        width,height = im.size
        left = 0
        top = 0
        right = height/16*9
        bottom = height
        im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
        #newsize = (1242, 2208)
        #im1 = im1.resize(newsize)
        im1.show()
        fullpath = os.path.join(outPath, 'rotated_'+image_path)
        rgb_im = im1.convert('RGB`enter code here`')
        rgb_im.save(fullpath)
```

Ideally, I'd like to be open up the cropped image and it shows this:
https://imgur.com/a/D9DZW0z

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve] along with input and output images that a) do work, and b) don't work so we can see what you mean.

Comment: I'm afraid **PIL** doesn't have the *"smarts"* to decide which part of your image is likely to be most interesting to you. You could consider making 3-5 crops of each image at 0, 25%, 50% and 75% of the width, or 0/33/66% and saving them as `image_1.png`, `image_2.png` and so on, then manually deleting the uninteresting ones.